# AWS DynamoDB Write permissions aren't working

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm doing a proof of concept with connecting to dynamodb, but I appear to be having issues with permissions.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-1:172777662485:table/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                    "${www.amazon.com:user_id}"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

The code:

```
DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(new AmazonDynamoDBClient("...", "...", new AmazonDynamoDBConfig() { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest1, MaxErrorRetry = 6 }));
var writeContext = context.CreateBatchWrite<Music>();
writeContext.AddPutItem(new Music() { Artist = "Test Artist", SongTitle = "SongTitle" });
writeContext.Execute();
```

The error I get is:

```
arn:aws:iam::...:user/DynamoDBTestUser is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:BatchWriteItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-1:172777662485:table/Music
```

Does anyone see anything wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your policy appears to be based on some of the samples from this document:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html

However, your code does not appear to be adding a record with a partition key matching the username.

So there are 2 possible solutions, depending on your desired outcome.

**Solution 1:**

Assuming you simply want to insert records into the table, you can use a policy such as:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }]
}
```

This policy grants the user fully DynamoDB access to any DynamoDB resource.

**Solution 2:**

If you want to restrict access to the table limiting the user to read/put records only for them, then you need to ensure your primary key attribute in your `Music` structure is populated with your IAM user name.

Comment: Looked through the differences and was able to keep most of my original policy.  I removed the condition you pointed out and that did it.